# Como se cria um menu em android totalmente animado

Tags: android, mobile, menu, selecteditem

[image: O menu do 2º celular]

O aplicativo tumblr tem um menu que ao apertar cada item/botão ele fica branco e se aperta outro volta a cor original. Alguém sabe o nome desse processo de indicar ao usuário que aquele botão foi clicado?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o 'setColorFilter' na ação do click do ícone. Veja o exemplo:

```
 img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img1.setColorFilter(0xff00aa00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        img2.clearColorFilter();
        img3.clearColorFilter();
    }
});
```

coloquei o 'onclick' como exemplo, no caso do menu, você utiliza o colorFilter na ação do menu...